# In Chrome 'transform-origin' is invalid?

Tags: css, google-chrome, developer-tools

My Chrome console returns `Invalid CSS property name` to a `transform-origin` CCS attribute as the site loads even though it works and I have a `-webkit-` prefixed version.

The target CSS looks like this:

```
-webkit-transform-origin: 0% 50%;
-moz-transform-origin: 0% 50%;
transform-origin: 0% 50%;
```

Is it really an issue?

Comment: The `transform` shorthand and related properties still need  to be prefixed with `-webkit` in Chrome, Safari and recent versions of Opera.

Comment: But I have it prefixed, thats why it works, does this not exist at all?

Comment: It does exist, maybe the problem lies elsewhere. Can you copy/paste the problematic code in your question?

Comment: @Adrift updated on the question

Comment: There's nothing wrong with those rules; maybe it's the selector that's causing problems? You can see [in this example](http://jsfiddle.net/dxAWf/) that it *should* work for WebKit browsers.

Comment: @Adrift Yes, I know, it is working, thats the irony here :P I am also using the latest version of Chrome!

Comment: Can you post the relevant code in a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: OMG, I have found the problem! This is not in Mozilla's documentation.

Comment: I have updated with an answer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've found the origin of my issue.

The problem is that `-webkit-` browsers don't accept the `transform-origin` attribute when it is isolated from a supporting attribute (an attribute that actually uses the `transform-origin`).

So, for example, if I use something like this, **`-webkit-` assumes it is wrong**:

```
#divOne{
   transform-origin:50% 50%;
   animation:jump 1s ease both;
}
@keyframe jump{
   from { transform: translateX(-20%) rotateY(-90deg); }
   to{ transform: translateX(0%) rotateY(0deg); }
}
```

It is wrong because the `origin` attribute is detached from the `transform` that is going to take use of it. Even though it works, it is not entirely correct on the browser's perspective.

It should be something like this **to be correct**:

```
#divOne{
   animation:jump 1s ease both;
}
@keyframe jump{
   from { transform: translateX(-20%) rotateY(-90deg); transform-origin:50% 50%; }
   to{ transform: translateX(0%) rotateY(0deg); transform-origin:50% 50%; }
}
```

Where both `transforms` are together on the same element.

Comment: I had this same issue and this is not the actual problem. On webkit, you just need to use the following value set for the transform-origin property: "x% y% z;". In my case, just using: "-webkit-transform-origin: 50% 85% 0;" solved the issue. Anyways, the 0 generates a bug in IE and in Mozilla browsers. That's why, if using SASS, you would need different values for each prefix. Non prefixed shouldn't have the "0" webkit needs.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question in simple terms is 'NO'. It is a perfectly valid property. There must be something else that's causing the error.

Read this:

> https://docs.google.com/document/d/1UsKm0ywILw9cuTRYlkhqMYTdzNcih6sO15u1eCzGgP8/edit?pli=1#

and this

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin#Browser_compatibility

Comment: Yes I know this, I actually read that documentation before. I am as surprised to this reaction as you probably are, don't have the slightest clue of what's happening here :P